# Populate additional rows based on existing row data in oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot, case

I have an existing table with structure and sample data as below :

```
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| S.No     | Desc  | ACC ID | Value  |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1        | abc   | ACC_1  | 1.23   |  
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Base on business conditions

```
select S.No, desc,
case when acc id=ACC_1 then value else 0 end as ACC_2,
case when acc id=ACC_1 then value else 0 end as ACC_3,
case when acc id=ACC_1 then value else 0 end as ACC_4,
from table1
```

Current output :

```
+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| S.No     | Desc  | ACC_2  | ACC_3  | ACC_4  |     
+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1        | abc   | 1.23   | 1.23   |1.23    |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Required output with same business logic :

```
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| S.No     | Desc  | ACC ID | Value  |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1        | abc   | ACC_2  | 1.23   |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1        | abc   | ACC_3  | 1.23   |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
| 1        | abc   | ACC_4  | 1.23   |
+----------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Do you always want three rows, with the account ID incrementing; and will that always start with 1? Might one of the 'new' account IDs already exist, and what happens if they do? It might be helpful to explain your business rules, or at least the logic for producing that output - including exactly what the account ID structure is and how it should be manipulated..

Comment: The account Id does not increment as shown above. it was just an example. the acc id's might be different . the business logic is based on the ACC_1 which exist, derived acc_x are populated based on the case statement, current the additional accounts are as column, moving forward would required them as additional rows

Comment: But always two new rows? How do you construct the new account IDs? It still isn't clear...

Comment: yes. the additional derived columns are constant, the derived column values are based on the existing acc id column values.

Comment: updated my example to clear confusion

Comment: Your account IDs are all hard-coded so it doesn't show what logic you are using to construct the new ones. There isn't enough data to guess what you want to happen more generally.

Answer (score 1):

Use CROSS joining `TABLE1` with `SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3` structure as in the following :

```
select t."S.No", t."Desc", rtrim(t."ACC ID",1)||level "ACC ID", t."Value"
  from dual d
  cross join table1 t
 connect by level <= 3;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61394/7)